# Как присвоить значение моей переменной через функцию?

Tags: javascript

Что-то я запутался, не могу понять, что не так, так что прошу Вас помочь)

Есть скрипт, в котором я хочу присвоить некоторое значение переменной `x` с помощью функции `x_value`, но в консоли выходить `undefined`, т.е. функция срабатывает позже `console.log()`. Как грамотно это сделать?)

```
            var x;
            function x_value(argument) {
                argument = "123"; // рандомная строка
            }
            x_value(x);
            console.log(x);
```

Туплю, но прошу помощи)

Comment: в таком виде - никак.

Comment: Тогда подскажите, пожалуйста, какую иерархию нужно создать, чтобы сработало?

Answer (score 1):

Функция срабатывает *раньше*, чем `console.log`, и это легко проверить, добавив в функцию еще один `console.log("внутри функции");`.

```js
var x;

function x_value() {
  return "123";
}
x = x_value();
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Кажется, это решение. Спасибо!